# javascript conflict with my datepicker and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have these codes in my webpage:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

It is working perfectly fine with my textbox. But since I have a dropdown function with my header:

[image]

I need these lines to make them work:

```
<%--<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js") %>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/bootstrap.min.js") %>'></script>--%>
```

When I try to paste them, the header dropdown is working but the problem now is my datepicker. Any tricks on this please?

ANSWER: made it work by pasting the pageresolve url to the top .

UPDATE QUESTION: what may cause this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are including jQuery.js twice. The second version is loading after the datepicker plugin has extended the original jQuery object and wipes it out .

You likely are seeing error `datepicker is not a function` or similar. You made no mention of errors thrown which is always the first thing to look for

Only include jQuery.js once and before all dependent plugins and code.

Comment: made it work, i pasted the revolver at the top. really have no idea why it worked lol. may i ask another question sir?

Comment: Just ask...if it's relevant to this issue will help more